# limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have calculated this limit
$$L=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}$$
 using polar coordinates as:
$$L=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|\cos \theta|+|\sin\theta|}{r}=+\infty.$$ 
My question is: are there other methods to calculate this limit? Thank you.

Comment: Why is angle constant ?

Comment: @A---B I think the meaning here is that for **any angle** ...etc. Then the limit is correct.

Comment: Yes because $|\cos\theta|+|\sin\theta|>0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that
$$
|x|+|y|\ge\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
so
$$
\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

Comment: We. Deduce that the limit equal to $+infty$?

Comment: @TheoryNombre Yes, by the squeeza theorem (in the infinity case).

Answer (score 0):

The expression is always non negative, so directly

$$\frac{|x|+|y|}{x^2+y^2}\ge\frac{|x|}{x^2+y^2}=\begin{cases}0\\{}\\\frac{|x|}{x^2+m^2x^2}=\frac1{|x|(1+m^2)}\end{cases}\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}\begin{cases}0,&x=0\\{}\\\infty,&y=mx\end{cases}$$

and thus the limit doesn't exist finitely

Comment: You have a problem in your calcul:

Comment: @TheoryNombre I don't think so, yet the idea should be clear any way.

Comment: Your first majoration is correct but the second is false.  We can't conclude that the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @TheoryNombre Either you misunderstood something or I did: the lower limit is taken on the line $\;y=mx\;$ and the limit is infinity of the minorating expression.

Comment: Then the limit does not exist?

Comment: @TheoryNombre The very least we can say is that it doesn't exist *finitely* .

Comment: @MyGlasses What?

Comment: No, the limit  is equal to $+\infty$.

Comment: @TheoryNombre Maybe...as I said, we can *at least* say the limit doesn't exist finitely. And I agree: it really seems to be infinity.